# How do I create actions with names that are not camel cased in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

My controller name is `api` and I want to create an action `update_user_infoAction()`, but when I try to create an action  `zf create action update_user_info Api`, I get an error :

> Action names should be camel cased.

Here is my terminal command and output:

```
volition@volition-H61M-DS2:/var/www/Dashboard_check$ zf create action update_user_info Api
```

> Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.
>   An Error Has Occurred
>   Action names should be camel cased.
>
> Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.11.10
>   Details for action "Create" and provider "Action"
>   Action
>   zf create action name controller-name[=Index] view-included[=1] module

Someone suggested that I use Zend Router but I am a newbie in Zend Framework so please suggest to me how I can create this action.

Note :- I do not want to change my action name

I am trying to create an action with an underscore. I've added this code to my bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap 
{ 
    protected function _initDoctype() 
    { 
         $dispatcher = $front->getDispatcher();
         $dispatcher->setWordDelimiter(array('.', '-'))->setPathDelimiter(''); 
    } 
}
```

However, when I do the following:  `zf create controller update_user_info`, I still get the same error.

*Update: As suggested by @emaillenin*

I am Trying this now :

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initDoctype() 
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $dispatcher = $frontController->getDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->setWordDelimiter(array('-', '.', '_'));
    }
}
```

http://localhost/Dashboard_check/public/api/update_user_info

but again, it doesn't work as it works for

http://localhost/Dashboard_check/public/api/updateuserinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bootstrap, add the following lines of code,

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$dispatcher = $frontController->getDispatcher();
$dispatcher->setWordDelimiter(array('-', '.', '_'));
```

When you call **www.example.com/api/update_user_info**

the following function will be invoked.

```
public function updateUserInfoAction() {

}
```

Keep your view script for this action in **update-user-info.phtml**

References -

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Question-about-underscores-in-controller-and-action-names-td656525.html

http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-general-discussions-1/general-q-zend-framework-2/underscore-action-name-1204.html

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/underscore-in-URL-td648359.html

Comment: 1. What is the error that you get when you access http://localhost/Dashboard_check/public/api/update_user_info ?
2. What the action name?